# Linux wireless hacking book

Tags: linux, wifi, defense

I am looking for recommendations on a good wireless hacking book. I would like something more focused towards the defensive, but a healthy knowledge of both would be great. I would also need it to go in depth on using wireless tools such as iwlist, iwconfig and maybe some simple scripting of these tools.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Hacking Exposed Wireless, 2nd Edition
- Seven Deadliest Wireless Technologies Attacks
- Unauthorised Access: Physical Penetration Testing For IT Security Teams
- Modern Cryptanalysis: Techniques for Advanced Code Breaking

The best I ever saw on defense was in the Linux Networking Cookbook, [Recipe 4.7. Making WPA2-Personal Almost As Good As WPA-Enterprise](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/networking/linux/9780596102487/building-a-linux-wireless-access-point/making_wpa2-personal_almost_as_good_as_w).

Comment: Big vote for Hacking Exposed Wireless, I personally know Johnny Cache and Josh Wright, and they are absolute ninjas when it comes to wireless in particular, but also security, protocol analysis, and cryptography in general.  So you don't just get a narrowly focused tricks, you get the full background of where things come from and what are their broader consequences.